# My simple jquery slide show using css zIndex is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a prensentation using jquery but the `next` button is working fine but the `back` button is not working as i expected please help me to fix this. thanks in advance.

[**i have tried here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/uW2ZU/)

here is my html code:

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="next">Next</div>
<div id="prev">Back</div>
<div class="slide s1">I'm slide 1</div>
<div class="slide s2">I'm slide 2</div>
<div class="slide s3">I'm slide 3</div>
```

​

here is my script:

```
var c=0;
var b=3;
$('.slide:gt(0)').hide();
$('#next').click(function(){
c++;
$('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : c}).show('slow');
});
$('#prev').click(function(){
b--;
$('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : b}).show('slow');
});​
```

Comment: the question is not clear enough. do you want to hide slide2 and show slide1 when you click back?

Comment: @rifky yes it's like page navigation

Comment: @Suresh Pattu: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't keep track of your slides properly. You don't need two indexes, just show a new slide on top of the others when the user clicks next, and hide the top slide when the user clicks back.

Like this:

```
var c=0;
$('.slide:gt(0)').hide();
$('#next').click(function(){
    if(c < $('.slide').size()-1) c++;
    $('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : c}).show('slow');
});
$('#prev').click(function(){
    if(c>0){
        $('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : c}).hide('slow');
        c--;
    }
});​
```

[See this fiddle (UPDATED TO WORK FOR UNDETERMINED NR OF SLIDES)](http://jsfiddle.net/uW2ZU/14/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define `var b = 3` just hide the slide before decrements on `back` button click.

```
var c=0;
$('.slide:gt(0)').hide();

$('#next').click(function(){
    c++;
    $('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : c}).show('slow');
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    //hide the slide
    $('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : c}).hide('slow');
    c--;
    $('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex : c}).show('slow');
});
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/vu2QD/)